# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' issue

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sympy
import math
from sympy import *
a, b, c, d, stf, lc = symbols('a b c d stf lc')
init_printing()
cxy = float(input("parametr Cxy "))      # 
print(cxy)
cz  = float(input("parametr Cz "))       # 
print(cz)
m   = float(input("masa ładunku "))      # 
print(m)
u   = float(input("parametr u tarcie "))
print(u)
g   = 9,80665
print(g)

frc = ((cxy - u * cz) * m * g)
frc.evalf(6)
print (frc)
print ("kompensacja", frc, "daN")
```

here's the code, and constantly on anaconda i'm getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-a7c280fc56b4> in <module>()
     21 print(g)
     22 
---> 23 frc = ((cxy - u * cz) * m * g)
     24 frc.evalf(6)
     25 print (frc)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

input is a float and there's still an error.
I'm running it on Anaconda 3, but it shouldn't be a problem to do simple multiplying.

Comment: `9,80665` isn't a float, it's a tuple of 9 and 80665. Write it with a decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `g` is a tuple: `g = 9,80665`

You probably meant to do `g = 9.80665`

It is possible to multiply an integer and a tuple (although the output will not be what you probably expect it to be), but it's impossible to multiply a float and a tuple.

Comment: i've checked all the floats dozen of times, and actuall answer was so simple... Stupid me :)